# XSLT Transformation for attached XML

Tags: xslt

I have a XML as shown below:

```
<NikuDataBus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/nikuxog_project.xsd">
<Header action="write" externalSource="NIKU" objectType="project" version="14.3.0.298"/>
<Projects>
    <Project  projectID="0000000284" projectName="Testing">  

        <Tasks>  
              <Task internalTaskID="5095022" name="PS2"  taskID="PS2"> </Task>
              <Task internalTaskID="5095038" name="PS"  taskID="PS"> </Task>
    </Tasks>      

    <Allocations/>
    <scenarioDependencies/>
    <InvestmentAssociations>
    <Allocations/>
    <Hierarchies/>
    </InvestmentAssociations>
    <CustomInformation/>
    <General/>
    <OBSAssocs/>

    </Project>
</Projects>
</NikuDataBus>
```

I want this XML to be transformed using XSLT and the end result should be only as shown below (only the Tasks tag). How can my XSLT be?

```
<Tasks>  
<Task internalTaskID="5095022" name="PS2"  taskID="PS2"> </Task>
<Task internalTaskID="5095038" name="PS"  taskID="PS"> </Task>
</Tasks>
```

Comment: Just so you know, we try to encourage posters here to make an attempt on their problem to start with, rather than posting the problem in the first instance. If you did in fact try something, please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can select and copy that element with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//Tasks" copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that `copy-namespaces="no"` is XSLT 2.0, without it or in XSLT 1.0 a simple copy will copy the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` as it is in scope from the root element.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Really appriciated. I will try this today and share the results.

Comment: Along with tasks I also get the version, encoding,xmlns:soapenv,xmlns:xsi. How can I remove them?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

    <Tasks xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  <Task .. </Task>
    </Tasks>

Comment: My code for selecting the Tasks  is listed below:
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
                                                                                                                
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//Tasks" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: As you can see in http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqw, the namespaces are not copied with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9.